# Call a function within a function matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I have defined a function called CARE_SAV which contains a recursive process, the code is

```
function [miu_tau_c,miu_tau] = CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1)
global miu_tau
global t
global miu_1
if  t > 1  
    miu_tau_c = beta(1)+beta(2) * ...
             [CARE_SAV(beta, Yt, t-1, miu_1)]+beta(3)*abs(Yt(t-1));
    miu_tau  = [miu_tau;miu_tau_c];  

else 
    miu_tau_c = miu_1;
    miu_tau  = [miu_tau;miu_tau_c];
end
```

The function itself runs perfectly. However, when I define another function (ALS) and call this CARE_SAV, the error keeps popping out saying the local variable may have been changed to match local variable value. And hence there is error on ALS line 6. The ALS code is shown below

```
function sum = ALS(tau,Yt,beta,miu_1,CARE_SAV)
s = 0;                                          % set the initial value for the ALS sum
global t
global miu_1
t = size(Yt,1);                                 % indicate the length of the simulated data 
[~,miu_tau]=CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1);          % call the CARE_SAV function to get miu_tau value
for i = 1:size(Yt,1)                            % conduct the ALS summation process for each t
    if Yt(i) < miu_tau(i)                       % set the indicator function
        s = s+abs(tau-1)*(Yt(i) - miu_tau(i))^2;
    else
        s = s+abs(tau-0)*(Yt(i) - miu_tau(i))^2;
    end 
end 
sum = s;
```

Can someone explain to me what I happening here? Much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't mix global variables and function arguments. In `CARE_SAV` you have `t` defined as a function input, and as a global variable. It should only be a function argument. (The same goes for `miu_1`). In general, using global variables is not best practice for Matlab coding, use function arguments instead.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for that. I guess my question now is not about the global variable. I make that global because I want the CARE_SAV function can use the argument I defined in ALS when I call it in ALS. I think my real question is how should I set the arguments value for CARE_SAV when I call it in ALS? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want `ALS` to have values that are generated by `CARE_SAV`, set them as output values of `CARE_SAV`. If you define something in `ALS` and want to use it in `CARE_SAV`, then set it as an input to `CARE_SAV`. If you want to change that value inside `CARE_SAV`, it must be an input and an output of `CARE_SAV`.

Answer (score 0):

In CARE_SAV, you have this:

`miu_tau_c = miu_1;` - being miu_1 a global variable.

Then, in the other function, you have `as input miu_1 AGAIN` and you call `global miu_1 AGAIN`. This is the issue.

Try to remove miu_1 from input in the second function. It might work, but using globals in functions like this it's not recommended.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that. The reason that I define global variables is that if I don't do so Matlab cannot find enough argument for CARE_SAV when I use it in the ALS function. So I guess my main problem is that how can I define the arguments for CARE_SAV when i want to call it in another function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look, you have CARE_SAV as an input in the ALS function. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are "calling" a function as an input of other function... you can call this other function inside, you don't need to put it as input!